# copyFromLocal error in pig grunt shell

Tags: shell, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have created director in hdfs for a project and its called cert_project
trying to copy csv file called Load Data.csv from local to hdfs.

```
$ hadoop fs -CopyFromLocal c:\Load Data.csv /home/edureka/aprl_25th_morng/cert_project/Load Data.csv
```

I am getting error. I tried at both terminal and grunt> (grunt shell)

Need help.

Comment: Use -copyFromLocal instead of -CopyFromLocal. use single quotes/ double quotes for the path which contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is space in file name it self. try renaming a file without space in file name or try one of this:

```
hadoop fs -CopyFromLocal 'c:\Load%20Data.csv' '/home/edureka/aprl_25th_morng/cert_project/Load Data.csv'
```

OR

```
hadoop fs -CopyFromLocal 'c:\Load%20Data.csv'  '/home/edureka/aprl_25th_morng/cert_project/'`
```

Space is represented as %20 in unix file system (NOT in hdfs). So if need to delete/copy file from hdfs, you will need to quote and without %20

```
hadoop fs -rm '/home/edureka/aprl_25th_morng/cert_project/Load Data.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -copyFromLocal , you are using capitaC..for more check this link for more [copyFromLocal](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#copyFromLocal)

Answer (score 0):

The command is copyFromLocal. you are using CopyFromLocal.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try

`hadoop fs -put $localFile $hadoopFile`

Make sure you have pre created parent directory

To create directory

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p $hadoopFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

use this 
hadoop fs -**copyFromLocal** c:\Load Data.csv /home/edureka/aprl_25th_morng/cert_project/Load Data.csv

the c in copyFromLocal must not be in CAPS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to run that command from Pig grunt shell you should write something like this :

```
sh hadoop fs -copyFromLocal $SOURCE_FILE_LOCAL $TARGET_HDFS_DIRECTORY
```

Make sure that source file is located on local file system of linux server from where you are running grunt shell and you have write access to directory on HDFS where you are trying to copy local file.